# How do I force the value in a textbox in a form to a default value when the value entered is invalid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

For example, in the controller view setup below everything works fine except that when I type something ridiculous in the textbox like 99/12/2014 it doesn't set it to the default 29/12/2014 when I press the submit button but it does set it to the default when I press the action link.

I have removed all other code because it is not relevant to the problem.

I want the textbox value to correct itself when I press the submit button if the value entered is not a valid date.

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(string myDate = null)
        {
            DateTime _myDate;
            if (!DateTime.TryParse(myDate, out _myDate))
            {
                _myDate = new DateTime(2013, 12, 29);
            }

            ViewBag.myDate = myDate = _myDate.ToString();

            return View();
        }
   }
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{   
    @Html.TextBox("myDate");

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
@Html.ActionLink("Select", "Index", new { myDate = ViewBag.MyDate })
```

Comment: You need to look at model validation and model binding. Simply put you're not using the features of .NET MVC properly. Look at client and server side validation with JQuery Validate on client side and System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace on server side.

Comment: @Marko: the MyDate textbox in the example is just intended to be used as a filter value if that makes any difference

Comment: see the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598386/jquery-validation-date